# How to use a character as attribute of a function

Tags: r, variables, character

I want to run a multiple comparisons analysis for the different variables of a model. My idea is as follows:

```
library(multcomp)
set.seed(123)
x1 <- gl(4,10)
x2 <- gl(5,2,40)
y <- rnorm(40)

fm1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)

for(var in c('x1', 'x2'))
{
mc1 <- glht(fm1, linfct=mcp(var='Tukey'))
print(summary(mc1))
}
```

When I run, I get the following error:
`Error en mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) : 
    Variable(s) ‘var’ have been specified in ‘linfct’ but cannot be found in ‘model’!`

That is, it is not possible to use a character to specify an attribute of the mcp function.
Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Update:** Make sure to see Hadley's answer for the better way of doing this, **without** resorting to string-pasting.  My answer will still be useful for explaining why that is harder-than-usual in this case.)

The peculiarities of `mcp()` require you to use the relatively brute force approach of pasting together the expression you'd like to evaluate and then passing it through `eval(parse())`.

The tricky bit is that `mcp()` interprets its first argument in a nonstandard way.  Within `mcp()`, `x1 = 'Tukey'` *does not* (as it normally would) mean "assign a value of `'Tukey'` to the argument `x1`". Instead, the whole thing  is interpreted as a symbolic description of the intended contrasts. (In this, it is much like more familiar formula objects such as the `y ~ x1 + x2` in your `lm()` call).

```
for(var in c('x1', 'x2')) {
    # Construct a character string with the expression you'd type at the command 
    # line. For example : "mcp(x1 = 'Tukey')"
    exprString <- paste("mcp(", var, "='Tukey')")
    # eval(parse()) it to get an 'mcp' object.
    LINFCT <- eval(parse(text = exprString))
    mc1 <- glht(fm1, linfct = LINFCT)
    print(summary(mc1))
}
```

Comment: Almost always better to use substitute instead of doing text manip.

Comment: Might be tricky here though. Another alternative would be do.call and setNames

Comment: @hadley -- I agree, and tried both of those first.  Partly tor the reason described in my answer it *is* trick in this case. If you can describe an alternative, I'd be really interested to see it, as I have a similar aversion to doing text manipulation.

Comment: @hadley, could you please provide an example using your proposals?

Answer (score 14):

It's generally better to avoid working with strings representing code wherever possible - it prevents errors that are hard to debug, and aesthetically is much more elegant.  This problem turns out to be fairly easy to solve if you use `do.call` and the `setNames` function:

```
var <- "x1"
cmp <- do.call(mcp, setNames(list("Tukey"), var))
glht(fm1, linfct = cmp)
```

You can't use `substitute` here because it does not allow you modify the names of function parameters.  I have some intuition for why this is reasonable, but not enough to explain it :/

If you're a package author, it's a good idea to provide an alternative version of functions that use unusual syntax so they can be accessed programmatically without jumping through hoops.

Comment: +1 Many thanks for taking the time to demonstrate `setNames()`' usage. I would not have guessed in a long long time that `x1=Tukey` really evaluates to a named list. I've now added a pointer to your answer at the start of my own.

Comment: The input to do.call is a named list.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried: `eval(parse(text='variable'))` 
or `assign`  ?