# Attribute variable name to a named vector

Tags: r

I have a string and and a number

```
cID = 'x1'
num = 1
```

I want to create a named vector

```
nvec = c(x1 = num)
```

but when I do the following, R interprets `cID` as `'cID'` and not as `'x1'`.

```
nvec = c(cID = num)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a one-line solution, use `setNames()`:

```
nvec <- setNames(num, cID)
nvec
# x1 
# 1
```

For an example in which `setName()` supplied a clean and elegant solution to a tricky problem, see @hadley's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448757/how-to-use-a-character-as-attribute-of-a-function).

Answer (score 5):

Try using "["

```
> nvec <- numeric(0)
> nvec[cID] <- num
> nvec
x1 
 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are asking for, but anyway

```
assign(cID, num)
```

means that

```
5 - x1
```

gives

```
[1] 4
```

Comment: That does not result in a named vector.

Comment: @DWin: Yes - I realised that, which is why I added the first line, but left it in as somebody might find it useful. For the actual question  `nvec <- num; names(nvec) <- cID` is the simple answer