# R Pass colname into glht function as variable in loop

Tags: r, for-loop, linear-regression

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here; am trying to use a loop to change the inputs to a formula, then generate a `glht` involving that formula. (`glht` = general linear hypothesis test). Thanks all!

```
df2 <- data.frame(f1=seq(1:5),f2=seq(4,8), y=sample(x=c(0,1),size=5,replace=TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(lapply(df2,factor)) # convert to factors

library(multcomp)

for (i in 1:(length(df2)-1)){
  fmla <- as.formula( paste("y~",colnames(df2)[i],sep=""))
  fm1 <- glm (fmla, family = binomial("logit"), data=df2)
 }
```

This much works; now I'm trying to dynamically pass in `f1` to make the line below:

```
  tuk <- glht(fm1, linfct=mcp(f1 ="Tukey"))
```

I have tried:

```
tuk <- glht(fm1,linfct=mcp(colnames(df2)[i] ="Tukey"))
```

but this gives:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in " tuk <- glht(fm1,linfct=mcp(colnames(df2)[i] ="
```

I thought this would be something to do with `parse/eval`.
So I tried:

```
e1 <- paste("fm1,linfct=mcp(",colnames(df2)[i],"=Tukey)",sep="")
glht(e1)
```

Gives:

```
Error in object$coefficients : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Error in modelparm.default(model, ...) :  no 'coef' method for 'model' found!
```

Then tried:

```
e1 <- parse(text=paste("fm1,linfct=mcp(",colnames(df2)[i],"=Tukey)",sep="") )
glht(e1)
```

Gives:

```
Error in parse.default(text = paste("fm1,linfct=mcp(", colnames(df2)[i],  : 
 <text>:1:4: unexpected ','
1: fm1,
      ^
```

Finally:

```
e1 <- as.expression(paste("fm1,linfct=mcp(",colnames(df2)[i],"=Tukey)",sep="") )
glht(e1)
```

Gives:

```
Error in UseMethod("vcov") : no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "expression"
Error in modelparm.default(model, ...) :  no 'vcov' method for 'model' found!
```

Comment: This is indeed a tricky problem. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448757/how-to-use-a-character-as-attribute-of-a-function), from late last year, are a couple of answers to an almost identical question. (Hadley's answer is particularly elegant.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An essentially [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448757/how-to-use-a-character-as-attribute-of-a-function) was asked and answered on SO last year.  The answer below uses the strategy outlined then by @hadley, explaining in a bit more detail why it works.

---

What's tricky about this problem is that you need to pass in each column name as the **name** of the sole argument to `mcp()`. Using `do.call()` is probably the best way to accomplish this.

What you want:

```
mcp(f1 = "Tukey")
```

How to get it when you have a variable `X="f1"`:

```
X <- "f1"
arg <- list("Tukey")
names(arg) <- X
do.call(mcp, arg)
```

In your case, you can do something like this:

```
require(multcomp)
df2 <- data.frame(f1=seq(1:5),f2=seq(4,8), y=sample(x=c(0,1),
                  size=5,replace=TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(lapply(df2,factor)) # convert to factors

nms <- head(colnames(df2), -1)
lapply(nms, 
       function(X) {
           fmla <- as.formula( paste("y~", X, sep=""))
           fm1 <- glm (fmla, family = binomial("logit"), data=df2)
           ## From here on down is the solution
           args <- list("Tukey")
           names(args) <- X
           cmp <- do.call(mcp, args)
           glht(fm1, linfct = cmp)
       })
```

Comment: Thanks, that was fast! Sorry I overlooked last years answer \*promises he searched\*. Would not have figured that out any time soon...

Comment: No problem. I don't know *how* you would have found that other one. The title of your question is much more precise, and I reckon it's more likely to be found by future searchers. Cheers.