# change function argument name

Tags: r

How to change function argument name. For example using substitute I can change function argument value or function name:

```
substitute(quote(F(x= A)), list(A= quote(B), F= quote(G)))
## result
quote(G(x = B))
```

but this doesn't work:

```
substitute(quote(F(x= A)), list(x= quote(y)))
## result
quote(F(x = A))
```

#
 EDIT (@Joran here is real example, maybe not so real but very close to what I am doing)

#

```
library("multcomp")
data("mtcars")

mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
xv <- c("gear","cyl")

for(v in xv){
 fo <- as.formula(paste("mpg",v,sep="~"))
 fit <- lm(fo,data=mtcars)
 print(eval(substitute(summary(glht(fit,linfct= mcp(vn="Dunnett"))),list(vn=v))))
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do either.  What is it you really want to do?  Typically in R, you might do `foo<- 'G'; bar<-'x' ; do.call(foo,bar)` to select a function and its arguments based on string objects.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @ What Carl & Joran said ("What is it you really want to do?!"). I'd change the arguments via `formals()` myself...

Comment: @Carl Witthoft can you write your answer

Comment: I thought you might be doing something with **multcomp**. See Hadley's or my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448757/how-to-use-a-character-as-attribute-of-a-function/8465005#8465005), which is essentially identical to your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking your example of something similar to the actual problem, why not do this:

```
library("multcomp")
data("mtcars")

mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
xv <- c("gear","cyl")

ll <- list("Dunnett")
for(v in xv){
  fo <- as.formula(paste("mpg",v,sep="~"))
  fit <- lm(fo,data=mtcars)
  names(ll) <- v
  print(summary(glht(fit, linfct = do.call(mcp, ll))))
}
```

Which gives:

```
     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts


Fit: lm(formula = fo, data = mtcars)

Linear Hypotheses:
           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
4 - 3 == 0    8.427      1.823   4.621 0.000144 ***
5 - 3 == 0    5.273      2.431   2.169 0.072493 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)


     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts


Fit: lm(formula = fo, data = mtcars)

Linear Hypotheses:
           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
6 - 4 == 0   -6.921      1.558  -4.441 0.000235 ***
8 - 4 == 0  -11.564      1.299  -8.905 1.71e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

The trick here is to note that the first argument to `mcp` is `...` which usually means we can pass in a list of the form `list(tag = value)`. We can't specify `tag` as `v` here, so just create the list `ll` with a single element `"Dunnett"` and then change the **names** attribute of this list in the loop to be `v`. Then use `do.call()` to arrange to call `mcp()` with this argument list.

And for completeness, as @Josh metions in a comment above, from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8465005/429846) from @Hadley the list can be more succinctly stated using the `setNames()` function:

```
for(v in xv){
  fo <- as.formula(paste("mpg",v,sep="~"))
  fit <- lm(fo,data=mtcars)
  print(summary(glht(fit, linfct = do.call(mcp, setNames(list("Dunnett"), v)))))
}
```

Comment: It can be shortened to: print(summary(glht(fit, linfct= setNames(eval(mcp(vn= "Dunnett")),v)))).

Answer (score 3):

Taking your question title and first line at face value why not copy the function and/or use `formals()` depending on whether the function name or the arguments need to change?

For the first one:

```
F <- function(x = A) {}
G <- F
formals(G) <- alist(x = B)

> args(G)
function (x = B) 
NULL
```

For the second one

```
F <- function(x = A) {}
formals(F) <- alist(y = A)

> args(F)
function (y = A) 
NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

If you must dynamically alter the name of the supplied arguments, you *could* do something like this:

```
cl <- quote(F(x = a))
names(cl)[names(cl) == "x"] <- "y"
cl
# F(y = a)
```

Answer (score 1):

After seeing the example of what you're really doing, you could also use `parse` and `sprintf`

```
 print(eval(parse(text=sprintf("summary(glht(fit,linfct= mcp(%s='Dunnett')))",
   v))))
```

Comment: I try to heed the advice of Thomas Lumley in this regard. `require("fortunes"); fortune(106)`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, but the question wasn't mine! (+1 to both your answers)

Answer (score 1):

As requested, comment moved to an answer:

I wouldn't do either. What is it you really want to do? Typically in R, you might do `foo<- 'G'; bar<-'x' ; do.call(foo,bar)` to select a function and its arguments based on string objects.